How to reliably read query parameters in Flutter web
I am working with Flutter 3.2.2 for the web and using following code to read the query parameters sent from another website to my website.
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;

var uri = Uri.dataFromString(html.window.location.href);
Map<String, String> params = uri.queryParameters;
final followers = params["followers"] ?? "0"

I am using universal_html package imported as html. However, sometimes the code works fine to retrieving the query parameters but not 100% as sometimes it doesn't seems to be able to read the followers and hence returning 0 although in the browser url bar, I can see the followers parameters in there and it not 0. What am I doing wrong and how do I make sure it works reliably everytime?

For best reliability, read the href before runApp and store the result.

@RichardHeap thanks for your comment. How do I do that?

Map<String, String>? initialQueryParameters;
void main() {
initialQueryParameters = getHref().queryParameters;
runApp(

Uri getHref() => Uri.parse(html.window.location.href);

Why are you using dataFromString rather than parse?

Thanks @RichardHeap. That seems very reliable from my tests. Do you want to answer it so I can mark it?

For best reliability, read the href before runApp and store the result. For example:
import 'dart:html'; // old style
import 'package:web/web.dart'; // new, preferred style, as you migrate to package:web

Map<String, String>? initialQueryParameters;

void main() {
  initialQueryParameters = Uri.parse(window.location.href).queryParameters;
  runApp(SomeWidget());
}

